# Sublime 3 & HTML: Find & Replace Function randomly capitalizes and lowercases letters?

Tags: html, replace, sublimetext3

Within my HTML code, I am trying to replace the string `Results/Model` with `<b>Results/Model</b>` using the Find and Replace function. This produces `<b>resulTs/model</b>` for some reason.

Functions that are toggled On:

- Case Sensitive
- Preserve case

Why does it do this in spite of those toggles?

Comment: You don't want `Preserve Case` to be turned on here; it makes the case of the replacement match the same position on the input matched string, which might not line up the way you expect. It's unclear if that's happening based on your question though; are you using a regex of some sort as the search criteria?

Comment: Nope, regex is off. It is just a Find and Replace of a simple string, replaced by another string, no fancy business.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you turn off `Preserve Case`? Can you provide an example of the input text and the match happening?